# How to select Column value as rows?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named ItemData in SQL Server as follows,

```
Create Table ItemDate( ItemName VARCHAR(50), Hyundai int,[I10/ I20] int,Maruti int);
insert into ItemData values('Coolant Change',150,150,150)
insert into ItemData values('Gear Oil Change',150,150,150)
insert into ItemData values('Brake Oil Change',350,200,200)
```

Now I want to query the table to insert into this table,

```
Create Table Result( ItemName VARCHAR(50), ModelName VARCHAR(50), Rate int);
```

where model name are Hyundai, I10/I20 & Maruti
please help me

Comment: your table ItemDate are not correct and your insert are not correct... Have you test your code?

Comment: there is so many things to be understood. 1. your table name is 'ItemDate' while insert is 'ItemData' 2. what is [I10/ I20] in Hyundai, compare to 150 150 150 entry. Its totally mismatch. Suggestions are, first write what is your table data and what will be your output data. Second, write the table structure with match data. So we can understand your question

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `unpivot` to achieve that.
try the following:

```
insert into Result
select ItemName, ModelName, Rate
from 
(
    select ItemName, Hyundai, [I10/ I20], Maruti
    from ItemData
)t
unpivot
(
    Rate for ModelName in ([Hyundai], [I10/ I20], [Maruti])
)upvt
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e17026b16c2e70a93375f020eda791a9)**.